# Python Django Separator

Tags: django-models

How to create a separator in django python.
what i want to do is create a - minus character every 3 numbers is it the right way to do in models ?

```
separator = models.IntegerField()
```

Expected actual results 
123-456-789-000

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have an integer model field and you want to change its representation when showing it to the user. You can use SerializerMethodField and create a read-only separator field to do that. Here is an example:

```py
# models.py
def YourModel(models.Model):
    separator = models.IntegerField()
    # your other fields...
```

```py
# serializers.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now
from rest_framework import serializers

class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    custom_separator = models.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_separator(self, obj):
        tmp = str(obj.separator)
        custom_separator = '-'.join(tmp[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(tmp), 3))
        return custom_separator
```